# Notion of Matrices over finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $S$ is a set of all possible square matrices over a finite field $F_p$.

What will the notion of determinant, rank, nullity, eigenvalue, eigenvector, adjoint, inverse of the matrix of $S$?

I have not find any standard book where all these info available.

If someone can suggest me book, that also would be fine.

My strong conviction about algebraic structure on $S$ as follows:

($S$,$\bigoplus_p$,$\bigotimes_p$) where $\bigoplus_p$ is modulo p addition and $\bigotimes_p$ modulo is p multiplication would form a Ring. Is it true?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. All the linear algebra works over any field. Only metric concepts: length, angles, inner products, require the field of real numbers (and the notion of positive elements). BTW: it is non-standard to use $\oplus_p$ and $\otimes_p$ for these operations. I have only seen them in some freshman algebra texts ostensibly as a reminder for the students that the entries are not real numbers. Many (including my freshman algebra course) use just $+$ for all additions (modular or not) and $\cdot$ for multiplication. In abstract algebra these symbols are reserved for something more complicated.

Comment: Symbolic correction can be done in a while. I need to understand about the structure. Please enlighten me.